# Setting the selected value of a drop down using a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I am using JQuery to create dynamic dropdown boxes (the selection of the first drop down filters options in the second). I am trying to create a check for a reverse use case (selection of second drop down forces associated selection in the first).

I have previously used this code to successfully set the active value:

```
$("#department option[value='Other']").prop('selected', true);
```

Now, I am trying to do the same as above, but by using a variable value instead of a hardcoded one. This is the code I have so far:

```
var selected_campus = $("#college")[0].options[$("#college")[0].selectedIndex].text.split(":",1).toString();
$("#campus option[value=selected_campus]").prop('selected', true);
```

The first line works fine and the desired value is successfully stored in `selected_campus`. However, the second line does not. How can I set the selected value of `#campus` to `selected_campus`?

Comment: Note that `split` returns an array, and you coerce that array to a string. The only reason it works is because you added a limit so you always get a single item in the array, and stringifying that array returns the expected result, hopefully. I would think something like `split(':').shift()` would be a better option? And using some data attributes to identify the options would be even better.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the feedback. I'm still quite new so I wasn't aware of shift() and it appears to do exactly what I need!

Comment: That entire line looks iffy, there's probably better ways all together to bind the options together in some sort of system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close; you have just to concatenate the variable `selected_campus` with the selector (string) using the `+` and single quotes `'` sign, like :

```
$("#campus option[value='"+selected_campus+"']").prop('selected', true);
________________________^_^_______________^_^
```

Instead of :

```
$("#campus option[value=selected_campus]").prop('selected', true);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to substitute the variable into the code:

```
$("#campus option[value='" + selected_campus + "']").prop('selected', true);
```

You would need the single quotes in case the value has spaces or other characters in it